# Can matching in a difference-in-difference test reduce bias from no anticipation assumption?

Tags: difference-in-difference

I am examining whether a policy resulted in increased profitabiltiy. The new policy was adopted in 2005 but announced in 2002. Is there a way to mitigate the no anticipation assumption? Is matching a correct approach?

Many thanks!

Comment: Does it make sense to perform a robustness test where we include leads to control for the anticipatory effect?

Comment: Hi, I think using the difference in difference approach once using 2002 and once using 2005 as your treatment year will help ot give you a better idea. Moreover, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160359/difference-in-difference-method-how-to-test-for-assumption-of-common-trend-betw    as this post shows you, you can test whether pretrends held in 2002 or not. If not then I presume you are better of using 2002 as your treatment year.