# which stat test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, proportion

I am doing a health interventional study in the community. I calculate the "pre-intervention" proportion of behavior of the community before applying the interventions. And after 1 years of various interventions applied at different times to the community, i do a post intervention proportion of the health behaviour.
Now I want to compare these two proportion and see if the interventions significantly improve the health behaviour in the community.

Please note that the community population can change a little over the time when pre and post-test were done by way of moving in/out, participating/not participating.

yamg

Comment: Do you have a control group so you can try a difference in difference analysis? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/160359/difference-in-difference-method-how-to-test-for-assumption-of-common-trend-betw