# Identical coefficients for difference-in-differences (DiD) with and without fixed effects (FE)

Tags: r, fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference

I have a data set which includes monthly luminosity data for 3,000 municipalities in Mexico. I also have one observation of several census covariates for each municipality. My data looks like this

```
Municipality  Date       Lum   Population Unemployment ....
18000113044  2012-04-01  45.3  4203       0.14
18000113044  2012-05-01  58.8  4203       0.14
18000113044  2012-06-01  40.3  4203       0.14
...
18000114021  2012-04-01  70.3  2043       0.21
18000114021  2012-05-01  85.2  2043       0.21
...
```

It also includes a treatment, post and interaction indicator.
My issue now is that if I perform a DiD regression on luminosity, I get identical coefficients regardless of whether I include individual FE or not. Only my standard errors get smaller.

My regressions:

```
OLS <- lm(log(Lum) ~ Treatment + Post + I(Treatment*Post) + Unemp + Illiteracy, data = Long) 

FE <- plm(log(Lum) ~ Treatment + Post + I(Treatment*Post) + Unemp + Illiteracy, index = c("Municipality"), data = Long, model = "within", effect = "individual")
```

What is also interesting is that when I drop 10% of all rows in my sample randomly, FE and OLS estimates are not identical anymore.

I can't really understand how this happens or whether my approach is correct and would appreciate your insights!

Comment: Welcome to CV. Does treatment begin at the same time for all municipalities? I answered a similar [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/458635/what-does-it-mean-if-a-fixed-effects-regression-gives-the-same-coefficients-as-o/458677#458677) recently. Follow-up here if anything is unclear and I can point you in the right direction.

Comment: Also, try a linear model that includes dummies for *all* municipalities. For exampe: `lm(log(Lum) ~ as.factor(Municipality) + Treatment*Post + Unemp + Illiteracy, data = Long)`. Do you get similar results? Note, `as.factor(Municipality)` represents *municipality* fixed effects. It is absorbing your treatment dummy. You often read in texts that difference-in-differences is a "special case" of fixed effects. If treatment timing is standardized, then it is not surprising that you are getting similar results, even with some covariates. Let me know if this makes sense and I can elaborate further.

Comment: Hey Thomas, thanks for getting back to me! Yes, treatment begins at the same time for all municipalities and they all remain treated. 
I estimated the regression with the manual dummies and get the exact same results as with the plm package for FE. 

Thanks for pointing me to your previously answered question! So as I understand it, my FE estimation is a generalization of my OLS estimation? But you write that it's not surprising that coefficients are *similar*. However, mine are identical, does that make a difference?

Comment: Also, the fact that FE & OLS estimates differ if a number of observations are left out randomly confuses me. Is it because then the number of treated moths is not identical for all units/treatment does not start at the same time for every municipality?

Comment: You can specify your model in multiple ways. See my answer below. Try out the different approaches and let me know if anything is unclear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin, I want to address some efficiency concerns with your code. First, you already instantiated the proper `Treatment` and `Post` indicators to a perform the "classical" difference-in-differences (DiD) analysis. It is not necessary to include the additive terms *and* also manually calculate the interaction inside of `I()`. Simply interact `Treatment` and `Post` and R will estimate the constituent terms of the interaction—for free. You could also drop `effects = "individual"` since the default behavior of `plm()` is to introduce individual effects. Thus, you can achieve the same results with the following:

```
OLS <- lm(log(Lum) ~ Treatment*Post + Unemp + Illiteracy, data = Long) 

FE <- plm(log(Lum) ~ Treatment*Post + Unemp + Illiteracy, index = c("Municipality"), data = Long, model= "within")
```

> My issue now is that if I perform a DiD regression on luminosity, I get identical coefficients regardless of whether I include individual FE or not.

It is entirely plausible to observe similar results when your panel consists of two well-defined treatment/control groups and two well-defined before/after periods. Thus, you can reestimate the former equation using municipality fixed effects *and* the interaction term (i.e., `Treatment*Post`) in the same model. This should yield identical DiD coefficients.

It should be noted, however, that the two equations will **not** produce similar results once you deviate from this setting. For example, suppose treatment adoption was *staggered* across municipalities; some municipalities get treated in earlier time periods while others get treated in later ones. Or, suppose a subset of treated municipalities withdraw from treatment permanently while others do not. Or, suppose municipalities move into and out of a "treated" status multiple times. Or, suppose you observe multiple treatment groups and each group receives a different "dose" (intensity) of treatment. You can clearly see the many departures from the traditional setting. In more complex settings, there is no guarantee the results from these two models will be similar. But I digress.

To help with your intuition, I encourage you to estimate the two models below. The former model uses `lm()` to estimate your DiD equation with municipality fixed effects; the latter uses `plm()` to estimate the same equation but uses the within transformation. Because treatment is standardized, both will produce identical estimates:

```
OLS <- lm(log(Lum) ~ as.factor(Municipality) + Treatment*Post + Unemp + Illiteracy, data = Long) 

FE <- plm(log(Lum) ~ as.factor(Municipality) + Treatment*Post + Unemp + Illiteracy, index = c("Municipality"), data = Long, model= "within")
```

Note, `as.factor(Municipality)` results in the estimation of dummies for *all* municipalities. This is algebraically equivalent to estimation is deviations from means. In the former equation using `lm()`, `Treatment` will be dropped, showing up as `NA` in your output summary; it is *collinear* with the fixed effects. This should not concern you. Its removal does not affect the coefficient on your interaction term.

In the latter equation, the inclusion of these dummies is redundant, as you already specified `model = within`. Your model summary using `plm()` will be much cleaner. In fact, the output from `summary(FE)` will omit `Treatment` for you. Either way, your estimates will be similar.

**Addressing concerns in the comments section...**

> So as I understand it, my FE estimation is a generalization of my OLS estimation?

Correct.

> But you write that it's not surprising that coefficients are similar. However, mine are identical, does that make a difference?

No.

> Also, the fact that FE & OLS estimates differ if a number of observations are left out randomly confuses me. Is it because then the number of treated months is not identical for all units/treatment does not start at the same time for every municipality?

Yes. You indicated in your post that you randomly removed 10% of your observations (rows). This could remove relevant pre- or post-exposure months. In your full panel, all municipalities might have two post-treatment months. In the abridged panel, a subset of municipalities might have only one—or none. Deliberately discarding observations at random creates an *un*balanced panel, and could most certainly impact your point estimates.

**Other thoughts...**

Your model also generalizes to an equation which includes dummies for *all* units and *all* time periods. In `lm()`, simply include a full set of dummies for municipalities and full set dummies for months.

The following equations should produce similar results as well:

```
OLS <- lm(log(Lum) ~ as.factor(Municipality) + as.factor(Month) + Treatment*Post + Unemp + Illiteracy, data = Long) 

FE <- plm(log(Lum) ~ Treatment*Post + Unemp + Illiteracy, index = c("Municipality", "Month"), data = Long, model= "within", effects = "twoways")
```

Suppose you have 30 municipalities observed over 36 months. The former model using `lm()` results in the estimation of 29 separate municipality effects and 35 separate month effects. Here, `Treatment` is dropped as it is collinear with the municipality fixed effects; `Post` is dropped as it is collinear with the month fixed effects.

The latter model using `plm()` does this in one shot if you include the unit and time index; this will require you to create a month variable in R (e.g., Jan-2018, Feb-2018, etc.). If you add `effects = "twoways"` to your model then a summary will only display the coefficient on your interaction term with the constituent terms removed for free.

Try out these different specifications and see if they give you the same DiD estimate. They should!