# Fixed effects difference in differences issue

Tags: fixed-effects-model, difference-in-difference, generalized-did

I am currently conducting a difference in difference (DID) analysis and fail to understand the benefits of fixed effects models in such cases. I ran a regular DID model with three regular independent variables (time, treatment and their interaction), however when I run the model with time (day) and stock fixed effects with the time and treat variable dropped, I essentially get the same results. Note: The dataset is panel data.

I initially tried to run the fixed effects version in order to control for the risk of every single company in my sample, but now I do not understand the benefit. Is the equivalence of results always the case?

Comment: Does the “treatment” affect all treated stocks on the same day?

Comment: Yes, the event ("treatment") affects all treated stocks on the same day.

Comment: Review my answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/452489/the-difference-between-did-and-fixed-effect-model/454261#454261) to help you understand the link between DiD and fixed effects. As for the equivalence, it is quite normal to observe similar results when your panel consists of two well-defined treatment/control groups and two well-defined before/after periods. Expect your results to change once you deviate from this setting. My answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/479047/identical-coefficients-for-did-with-and-without-fe) should clear things up.